# Abrir campo com value setado, porém podendo ser editado

Tags: react-native

Estou utilizando o `floatingLabel` do [NativeBase](https://nativebase.io/):

```
<Item floatingLabel>
    <Label style={{ color: branco }}>Local da ocorrência</Label>
    <Input multiline={true} numberOfLines={4} value={this.state.place.toString()} />
</Item>
```

Este recebe o endereço a partir do API e já vem preenchido, porém se o usuário tentar editar não consegue.

Tentei usar o `defaulValue` que, como descrito na [documentação](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) do `TextInput`:

> Provides an initial value that will change when the user starts
>   typing. Useful for simple use-cases where you do not want to deal with
>   listening to events and updating the value prop to keep the controlled
>   state in sync.

```
<Item floatingLabel>
    <Label style={{ color: branco }}>Local da ocorrência</Label>
    <Input multiline={true} numberOfLines={4} defaultValue={this.state.place.toString()} />
</Item>
```

Mas este não funcionou, simplesmente não aprece valor nenhum ao carregar.

Alguma ideia de como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando o método render é chamado, o valor do input vem do estado `this.state.place`. O input só vai mudar de texto se o estado for mudado. Entao você tem que usar a prop `onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ place: text })}` pra mudar o estado e fazer o render() ser chamado novamente com o novo valor de `this.state.place`.

De acordo com a documentação o Input do NativeBase vem do TextInput do React Native, então deve ser capaz de receber a prop onChangeText.

Ref https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#Form

> Input is a NativeBase component built on top of React Native's TextInput