# Não consigo editar conteúdo do Input que retorna endereço

Tags: javascript, react-native

Através deste código recebo o endereço atual do aparelho:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        }, () => this.getGeocode());
      },
       (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
       { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000 },
     );

    }
    // Retorna o endereço a partir da geolocalização
    getGeocode() {
     axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+ this.state.latitude +','+ this.state.longitude +'&key=__API_KEY__')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
        this.setState({
            place: response.data.results[0].formatted_address
        })
     }).catch((error) => {
       this.setState({ error: error.message })
     });
  }
```

E imprimo o endereço neste campo:

```
<Item floatingLabel>
  <Label style={{ color: branco }}>Local da ocorrência</Label>
  <Input multiline={true} numberOfLines={2} value={this.state.place.toString()} />
</Item>
```

Até ai tudo bem, porém **eu gostaria que caso o usuário quisesse este pudesse apagar o endereço e entrar com um outro**, mas atualmente, se tentar apagar ele fica preenchendo de novo.

Pensei em colocar um botão ali, tipo "Entrar com endereço diferente", mas não teria como simplesmente chamar uma vez o endereço, sendo que seja possível editar esse?

Comment: (1) De onde vem os componentes Item, Label, Input? (2) O componente de input tem valor setado pelo estado, `this.state.place.toString()` e sempre vai ser isso toda vez que `render` for chamada. Normalmente, campos de texto sao controlados e tem um onChangeText prop que atualize o estado com os novos dados digitados.

Comment: @nbkhope vlw, dei uma pesquisada sobre o `onChangeText` e consegui assim: `onChangeText={(place) => this.setState({place})}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicada de [Abrir campo com value setado, porém podendo ser editado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249993/abrir-campo-com-value-setado-por%C3%A9m-podendo-ser-editado)

Adicione a prop `onChangeText` ao Input para poder atualizar o estado do componente com um novo valor para `place`.

```
<Input onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ place: text })} />
```

(Outras propriedades do Input foram omitidas)

Comment: Nossa fiquei tanto tempo longe do projeto que nem lembrava que já tinha questionado aqui, mas ainda bem que dessa vez obtive resposta, e obrigado de novo por sinal